# Wordpress - redirect after time elapsed on the whole website

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, plugins, hook

I have a website which i need to let the user navigate and read articles and so on and after , say 3 minutes or 5 , redirect him to surveymonkey.com.

I have made a plugin to do the job and append it to "init" hook

```
    function redirect_after_time() {
     header( "refresh:10;url=http://www.google.com" );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'redirect_after_time' );
```

The thing is , if the user navigate/refresh the page the "init" hook is called again and will begin the count again before redirecting to the surveymonkey.com

Any help ?

Comment: In addition to your solution use a session var to store the time of the first request for the user and check against it on each request.

Comment: How about opening a popup window when the site loads, and handle the function in that - then open a new window with the surveymonkey.com site, in a maximised window?